# use 'or' condition for dosnthave and orWereHas together in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Imagine that we have a `user` model that has a one to many relation for its `images`. Each user can have multiple images and each image belongs to one user.

I want to create a query to get users that don't have images or if it has images, it is confirmed.

```
$desired_users = User::doesntHave('images')->orWhereHas('images', function($query) {
$query->where('is_confirmed',1);
})->get();
```

But this wouldn't give me the correct users. I don't know how I can use 'or' condition in this case. Would you please help me out where I'm messing this up?

Comment: I think you can check with `NOT IN(the user ID)`

Comment: @IbrahimHammed What do you mean? can you give me an example please?

Comment: Like getting list of user's id and build query with `whereNotIn()` . ie `User::whereNotIn('user_id', [list_of_users_id])->get();`

Comment: @IbrahimHammed This is not what I want! I want to use `user/image` relations to get what I want.

Comment: How about `DB::table('user')->join('image_table', 'user.id', 'image_table.user_id)->whereNotIn('', [])`